# PHP file read error on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, php, file-permissions

I'm getting the following error from `fopen` and `file_get_contents`:

```
failed to open stream: Operation not permitted
```

This only occurs when accessing a script via localhost in a browser — on the command-line, it works as expected.

The server is running as my local user, and the script itself is definitely executing as that user — confirmed via `get_current_user()`.

The script thinks the file should be readable — confirmed via `is_readable()`.

I cannot find anything obvious in php or apache config that would cause this. I recently upgraded to Big Sur, and this is the first example of such a problem I can remember. I suspect it has something to do with an opaque security setting in macOS relating to reading files outside the document root.

Any thoughts on how I can solve the problem or further diagnose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*I'm not on a Mac, but this is what I found.*)

The information returned by the `is_readable()` function seems to be
false, and PHP lacks the entitlement to read these files.

An explanation is found in the post [Detecting if a file is
readable](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=50698.0):

> On Windows and Linux (and older versions of MacOS), the LazFileUtils
> FileIsReadable function was sufficient to determine if a file has read
> permissions set. However, this returns the global permissions for this
> file. With recent/upcoming versions of MacOS, **applications by default
> are supposed to work in a sandbox with limited entitlements**. They are
> only supposed to be able to read a file if the user has explicitly
> associated it with that application, for example by dragging and
> dropping or by using a file open dialog.
>
> Consider an application that wants to read the file
> `~/Desktop/notes.txt`. This files global permissions mean that this file
> CAN be read by programs. However, our specific program is not entitled
> to read the file. Unfortunately, `FileIsReadable` simply reports that
> the file is readable globally. **Yet when the application actually
> attempts to read the file it has an error**.

One possible solution is found in the article
[Under Catalina MacOS 10.15 PHP under Apache has restricted access to some files via file links possibly by privacy changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327503/under-catalina-macos-10-15-php-under-apache-has-restricted-access-to-some-files):

> Catalina has more restrictive permissions. The fix is easy: enable
> full disk access for http. To do this:
>
> System Preferences => Security & Privacy => Full Disk Access
>
> Navigate to the root folder of the disk and press Cmd+Shift+. (to view
> all the folders under root) and then go to
>
> /usr/sbin/
>
> select "httpd" and restart it (apachectl -k restart).

Another answer is found in the post
[Folders in iCloud Drive change their permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392347/folders-in-icloud-drive-change-their-permissions):

> I had the same problem, trying to run a server as an unprivileged user
> that needs read access to Documents, while Documents is in iCloud
> Drive. Normal UNIX file permissions didn't stick. I solved it by using
> ACLs to grant access.
>
> `chmod +a "_www allow list,search" Documents`
>
> In this example `_www` is the unprivileged user your server is running
> as. Use `ps axu` to find out what user that is for you.
>
> The folders inside Documents should work like normal with UNIX file
> permission bits, so you only have to do this for the Documents folder
> itself.
>
> For more info on ACLs, see here
> [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/introduction-to-os-x-access-control-lists-acls/)
> and `man chmod`.

Not being on a Mac, I can't test any of the above methods, or give additional
information.

Comment: Brilliant. Your first fix — Full Disk Access — was what did it for me. I find it incredibly frustrating that macOS takes the transparent permissions model of Unix and wraps it in an opaque non-discoverable layer such as this, but it's good to get it resolved — thanks!